# Reflection of EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, boundary-conditions

In reflection of e m waves at the boundary, to show the  reflected magnetic fields we put negative sign in the unit vector, example, if the B is along z direction we put (-k) in he reflected wave,  not putting (-j) in electric field if E is along Y direction, though both fields are perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The reason we do this is that the Poynting vector $\vec{E}\times\vec{H}=\vec{E}\times\vec{B}/\mu$ is in the same direction as the wave vector $\vec{k}$ and shows the wave direction.

So, to convert a forwards travelling plane wave to a backwards travelling version of itself, we need to change the sign of *only one* of the $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$, If we changed the sign of them both,  $\vec{E}\times\vec{H}$ would be unchanged, and we'd be talking about a forwards travelling wave again.

So we switch the sign of only one of them. It does not matter whether we switch the sign of $\vec{E}$ or $\vec{B}$, the results are the same, even though I think every treatment I have seen switches the sign of $\vec{H}$ and leaves $\vec{E}$ positive. Whichever way we do it, $\vec{E}\times\vec{H}$ now points in the opposite direction, as fitting for the reflected wave.

Comment: Okay. But the direction of which field is actually reversed?

Comment: @Razor It doesn't matter. You assign co-efficients to your forwards and backwards fields at the boundary. Then you write down equations imposing continuity of both field vectors across the boundary. The equations will give you the co-efficients that are good for your assumed directions: negative signs in the solution simply betoken a "wrong" choice to begin with and thus "put it right".